# How to write to a file provisioning from Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, provisioning, vagrantfile

Hi I'm trying to add a Directory Index directive to the default VirtualHost for Apache from the Vagrantfile. I'm wondering if there is a way to edit a file from the Vagrantfile (I'm usung inline SHELL). I know I could copy an entire VH file to the guest machine, but I want to know how to write into files if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with ansible like this:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose   = "vv"
    ansible.become    = true # execute as root
    ansible.playbook  = "relative_path_to_ansible_file/playbook.yml"
  end
```

or with a shell

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = "echo $1"
    s.args   = "'hello, world!'"
  end
end
```

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html